# Sencha Architect migration translated labels missing

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect

I migrated Sencha Architect v4.X to v5.7 and EXTjs from v5.1 to v7.6.

Labels in the userinterface are displayed only when specified as `text: 'Nr.'`
but not when specified as `bind: { text: '{name}'}`.

Example in gridview:

```
columns: [
    {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        width: 70,
        dataIndex: 'number',
        text: 'Nr.',
        filter: {
            type: 'number'
        }
    },
    {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        flex: 1,
        minWidth: 130,
        width: '',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        bind: {
            text: '{name}'
        },
        filter: {
            type: 'string'
        }
    },
```

My `de.json` is:
"name" : "Name"
Executing the command in browser console gives the translated string.

What am i missing here?

Expected no change in language translation behavior.

Comment: Please put some effort into formatting your code blocks. If you don't care enough to do that, many people won't have enough to bother trying to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same problem. It was a change in regex by Sencha team.
The change happened at Extjs 5.1

Extjs 5.1 (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.4/api/src/ViewModel.js.html)

```
expressionRe: /^(?:\{[!]?(?:(\d+)|([a-z_][\w\-\.]*))\})$/i,
```

Extjs 7.6. (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/src/ViewModel.js.html)

```
expressionRe: /^(?:\{(?:(\d+)|([a-z_][\w.]*))\})$/i,
```

In Extjs 7.6 bindings with "-" are not possible, you may change it to "_" or something else.
So instead of text:{your-text} use text:{your_text}

I dont understand why Sencha did that, it was an anoying experience to fix that...